# An audit failed, but the question has two different problems in it, one resolved, and one not. Should they be separate questions?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I'm really really confused. I just failed [this audit in the Reopen Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/33278357), and the target question is [react native The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadatais greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74343318)

Yet, the question displayed in the audit lists two problems. The first one was resolved that then revealed a second error that is not actually related.

How does this fall within the guidelines? I thought it violated the close rule of **Needs more focus**:

> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Yet this question clearly asks a second question: *"after I added the first solution new error again..."*. This error is not related to the build bug that was answered because of mismatching SDK versions. Is it because the OP has missed a required value from the manifest? Now it seems to have a second question without any answers pertaining to it, so there isn't any marked answer.

I really don't think the question should be in the audit system, but if it should be, what is the reason it's allowed when it seems to go against a Close rule? I'm not even sure why it was allowed to reopen, being that it seems to violate a close rule.

Now, while this has not banned me, if I get another audit wrong (and if this is incorrect how many others are?) in 30 days, will I get banned from it?

Comment: *"what is the reason it's allowed"* such questions are automatically added as "known good posts" (there also "known bad posts" which have either a lot of downvotes or are closed/deleted), that's why it got added as an audit. That system relies on users to properly maintain and vote on posts. This hasn't happened here, that's why second question is still there. Those traps in the audit system can occur and if you get banned because of them you can still create a meta question, a mod can look into it and maybe revert the ban.

Comment: @Tom I would like to add this is not the first time I have had this issue where I think it violates a different close rule than what it's listed as closed for, click close and it does not ask me why I think it should be closed like a normal "leave closed" would, I think that SE should implement an audit correction system of oh a lot of people failed this audit because they said it should be closed for another reason... perhaps we remove it from the audit system and remove all the strikes or block against ppl who failed this.

Comment: FWIW, I've rolled the question back to the revision before they added the other question.

Comment: According to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74343318/timeline) it went through the Close Votes review queue before being used as an audit, which means that someone had already voted to close it previously. In my opinion questions that have previously received close votes should never be used as known-good audits.

Comment: Curious: what directed you to post in meta? Was it your knowledge of how the site works, or is there now information in the "audit failed" message about how to dispute a result? (As I recall -- this was years ago -- after failing an audit that I disagreed with, I did not see a procedure to dispute the result, so I simply quit going through the review queues. Path of least resistance.)

Comment: The TL;DR here is the question was highly upvoted. As Donald Duck noted, the "known good" audits here aren't always "good". This is one of those rare times where the system pits the audit against the will of other voters (which a prior CM noted in a dupe is a place we don't want to be). If you ever get review banned due to one of these, post on Meta and we generally will unban you after a review.